# Display app icon is becoming white while changing the language in iPhone device Setting

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, localization

At First launch the app icon appears but changing and setting the other language in device settings and going back to home screen, the display app icon disappears and becomes white.

Any idea why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068296/why-is-app-icon-white) and [Quick Fix For White Icons Bug After iPhone 4S, iPad 2 Untethered Jailbreak](http://www.ijailbreak.com/jailbreak/absinthe-white-icons-bug-fix/).

Comment: ThankQ .. but i didn't get answer :|

Comment: any reason for downvote?

Comment: ya, this is not a common issue. Non constructive and too localised! Make sense?

Comment: @Dpk: if somebody work on Localization , then sometime he will get this issue. We just need to restart the device. It happens so i asked. Its purely relevant.

Comment: @Neelz OK, but please check your own comment (last one) for the accepted answer and do check FAQ for "non constructive" questions definition

Comment: @Neelz can you edit this question? I would like to withdraw my down vote as its already closed as non constructive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it happens because of something similar to caching. Try to delete your application from a device for testing and press "Alt + Shift + Cmd + K" in xCode to clean a build folder. I hope this will be helpful

Comment: My other apps are showing app icon. But this app is having localization. First time at launch it shows the icon but when i change the language and come back to home screen it disappears and become white.

Comment: 1)have you tried my suggestion?
2)what way do you use to setup an app icon?

Comment: Yes i tried, but it didn't work so i added a comment.

Comment: i have added Icon.png and Icon@2x.png to Resources folder.

Comment: @NeelamVerma check your icon files name in your plist file may be they should be different.......

Comment: @aakilladhani: they are with correct names. :|

Comment: Hey guys .. My device got some problem .. I reset my device and it start working.. Anyways thx for the response :)